# Missing } inserted error in tabular environment?

Tags: compilation-error

I have the following code. And error is shown in line 19.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{geometry}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\centering
%\includegraphics[width=2.8cm,height=3.4cm]{Image/dulogowhite.png}\\
 \tikz[remember picture,overlay] \node[opacity=0.08, inner sep=-3pt] at (current page.center){\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{Image/dulogoblue.png}};
{\scshape\LARGE University of Dhaka \par}
{\scshape\Large Department of Botany\par}
{\huge\bfseries Plant Physiology(304)\par}
\vspace{2.5cm}
Submitted by \\
\vspace{0.5cm}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{l}
{\Large \textit{Name}: Md.Shakherul Islam\\\textit{Roll}: SH-55037\\\textit{Reg}: 2015-217-471\\\textit{Year}: 3\textsuperscript{rd}\\\textit{Session}: 2015-16}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\vfill
Submitted to \\
\vspace{0.5cm}
Md. Saiful Islam\\ Lecturer\\Botany
\vfill
% Bottom of the page
{\large \today\par}
\end{titlepage}
\clearpage
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `{\Large\begin{tabular}{l}` and `\end{tabular}}` instead of ` \begin{tabular}{l} {\Large` and `}\end{tabular}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've tag `\Large` inside `{tabular}` environment, please group this outside, modified codes given below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{geometry}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\centering
%\includegraphics[width=2.8cm,height=3.4cm]{Image/dulogowhite.png}\\
% \tikz[remember picture,overlay] \node[opacity=0.08, inner sep=-3pt] at (current page.center){\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{Image/dulogoblue.png}};
{\scshape\LARGE University of Dhaka \par}
{\scshape\Large Department of Botany\par}
{\huge\bfseries Plant Physiology(304)\par}
\vspace{2.5cm}
Submitted by \\
\vspace{0.5cm}
\begin{center}
{\Large  \begin{tabular}{l}
 \textit{Name}: Md.Shakherul Islam\\\textit{Roll}: SH-55037\\\textit{Reg}: 2015-217-471\\\textit{Year}: 3\textsuperscript{rd}\\\textit{Session}: 2015-16
\end{tabular}}
\end{center}
\vfill
Submitted to \\
\vspace{0.5cm}
Md. Saiful Islam\\ Lecturer\\Botany
\vfill
% Bottom of the page
{\large \today\par}
\end{titlepage}
\clearpage
\end{document}
```